# preg_match_all except if tag has class

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex which replaces shortcodes in my texts.

```
[test_code]

<textarea class="ignoreShortCodes">[test_code]</textarea>
```

Now both `[test_code]` blocks are going to replaced, but I don't want this.

Now here is my regex:

```
/\[([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\s?([^\]]*)\]/is
```

Please note, a shortcode can contain arguments like:

```
[test_code name="test"]
```

Who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*ignoreShortCodes).*\\[([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\\s?(?:[^\\]]*)\\]/im
```

which will match every lignes that doesn't contain the class `ignoreShortCodes`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!